# BigQuery API 'Copy job failed: no such field' when restoring json backup

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery API to backup tables to cloud storage, which works fine. When I try to create a restore job to load the backup files into BigQuery, however, I get an error saying that the copy job failed because there is 'no such field' for all the fields specified in the schema. The schema is kept in the repo as a JSON file and other api operations make use of it, and this issue happens with all the tables we have so I don't think schema changes are the issue. The job configuration and an example error are below, any ideas would be appreciated.

```
{'configuration': {
    'load': {
        'destinationTable': {
            'projectId': 'someproject',
            'tableId': 'backuptesttable',
            'datasetId': 'warehouse_dev'
        },
        'sourceFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        'sourceUris': ['gs:///followers/backupfile.json.gz'],
        'schema': 'schema data loaded from file'
    }
}
```

**Update**

I switched the table I'm testing on to 'followers' since it's a bit simpler. This is the schema:

```
[{'mode': 'required', 'name': 'time', 'type': 'timestamp'},
 {'mode': 'required', 'name': 'followers', 'type': 'integer'},
 {'mode': 'required', 'name': 'account', 'type': 'string'},
 {'mode': 'required', 'name': 'platform', 'type': 'string'},
 {'mode': 'required', 'name': 'source', 'type': 'string'}]
```

And this is the full error:

```
Copy job failed: {'state': 'DONE', 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:110 / Line:2 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:220 / Line:3 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:330 / Line:4 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:440 / Line:5 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}], 'errorResult': {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'File: 0 / Offset:440 / Line:5 / Column:12 / Field:followers', 'message': 'no such field'}}
```

This is an example row from the backup file:

```
{"followers":"12345","account":"some account","platform":"plus","source":"API","time":"2015-04-14 14:58:13 UTC"}
```

'followers' is always the first field in the row, but bigquery seems unable to recognize it as being a valid field given the schema...I tried rearranging the order of the fields in the schema file to no avail.

Comment: Can you include the schema in your example? From the error message, it looks like File: 0 / Offset:44215 / Line:5 / Column:14 includes a field 'facebook_id' that wasn't in your schema definition. Additionally, if you can provide the project_id:job_id of a job that failed with this error we might be able find additional information.

Comment: I added the schema, the full error, and an example row.